CG amp in LT Spice | floating node drror
I'm trying to simulate CG amp in LT Spice.

Here's the circuit diagram of my project.
When I run it, I get an error message saying this:
LTspice 24.0.12 for Windows
solver = Normal
Maximum thread count: 16
tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
WARNING: Node 40E-9 is floating.
WARNING: Node MJSW is floating.
WARNING: Less than two connections to node 40e-9.  This node is used by cjsw.
WARNING: Less than two connections to node mjsw.  This node is used by cjsw.
Model "nmos": Oxide thickness thinner than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Instance "m1": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Instance "m1": Width narrower than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Direct Newton iteration for .op point succeeded.
Singular matrix:  Check node 40e-9
Iteration No. 1
Fatal Error: Singular matrix:  check node 40e-9
Iteration No. 1
This circuit has floating nodes.
I spent several hours solving this, but everything failed.
Need some help

solved!
problem was that the .model~ line has an 'enter' between MJ - 0.35 and CJSW = ~~
Hope this help someone like me

Please select your answer so that it can be considered closed and doesn't keep attracting eyes wondering if there is something more needed. And good job with your own debugging of the problem!
